# CCK field. how to use dynamic names to call CCK fields? (like: $node->$cckname)

Tags: entities

I have several cck image fields. Each field has a consecutive name, for example:

**field_photos_1**, 
**field_photos_2**,
**field_photos_3**,
**field_photos_4**
... until 20

So my question is: How to call the image fields in a loop?

for example (pseudocode:)

```
for($i = 0; $i >= 20; $i++){
$cckname = 'field_photos_'.$i; //$cckname is changing the image field name, then...
echo "<img src='/".$node->$cckname[0]['filepath']."'";
}
```

The question in a general way could be: how to use dynamic names to call fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an array directly from a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) class property.

You have two options:

```
for($i = 0; $i >= 20; $i++){
  $cckname = 'field_photos_' . $i;
  $cckfield = $node->$cckname;
  echo "<img src='/" . $cckfield[0]['filepath'] . "'";
}
```

Or typecast the node object as an array:

```
for($i = 0; $i >= 20; $i++){
  $cckname = 'field_photos_' . $i;
  $node_array = (array) $node;
  echo "<img src='/" . $node_array[$cckname][0]['filepath'] . "'";
}
```

Comment: the two snippets do their job, thanks! and thanks for your explanation about variable variables

Answer (score 2):

You use curly braces `{}` to delimit the variable inside your reference, as

```
for($i = 0; $i >= 20; $i++) {
  $cckname = 'field_photos_' . $i; //$cckname is changing the image field name, then...
  echo "<img src='/" . $node->{$cckname}[0]['filepath'] . "'";
}
```

This syntax is used in many places in Drupal core, see for example [hook_field_prepare_translation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_prepare_translation/7).

Comment: I thought the same thing but I tried `$node->${$cckname}[0]` which, in hindsight, is *obviously* the wrong syntax. d'oh